# DirectX C++, objidl.h Ошибка 'identifier'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, directx

Здравствуйте.

Не знаю, получу ли ответ на вопрос но все же.

Собрал пример из учебника по `DirecX 9` в `VS 2010 Express`.

На этапе компиляции, в подключаемом из `DirecX SDK` хедере `objidl.h` всплывает ошибка:

```
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Finish_Pull( 
           /* [length_is][size_is][out] */ __RPC__out__xcount_part(cRequest, *pcReturned) BYTE *buf,
            /* [out] */ __RPC__out ULONG *pcReturned) = 0;
```

`error C2061: syntax error : identifier '__RPC__out__xcount_part'`
`error C2059: syntax error : ')'`

Вторая ошибка указывает на скобку перед `= 0;`

Знаю, что тема очень узконаправлена, но покопавшись в инете нашел массу жалоб на эту
 ошибку на англо/китайско язычных сайтах, ничего не понял, что там написано.

**Вопрос:** В чем причина этих ошибок? В куске кода вроде бы все правильно.

В книге пример сделан в `VS 7` потому как книги по `DX9` датируются 2003-2006 годами. и учебника по работе с `DX9` в версиях `VS` выше `7` я не нашел.

Сделал как написал `stck`

[image]

В `Executable` не надо ничего добавлять вроде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подобная проблема описана [здесь](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/9779c9ad-e20c-4d73-9703-a1a308775e4b/).

> Did you install the DirectX SDK?  If the DirectX SDK was installed after the Windows SDK, the DirectX \include directory will come before the Windows SDK \include directory in your PATH.  This means that Visual Studio will be build with the version of objidl.h that ships in the DirectX SDK.  You must build with the version of objidl.h that ships in the Windows 7 SDK.
>
> Please look at your VC++ Directory Settings in VS and see if the Windows SDK include path (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include) is at the top of the list.  This will make Visual Studio use the SDK resources first.  You should also change the settings for the Executable and Library directories, so that the Windows SDK directories are at the top.
>
> To change the directories, in Visual Studio IDE, go to Tools, Options, Projects and Solutions, VC++ Directories.

Comment: Сделал как надо, щя скрин оформлю, но ошибка осталась.